# IKVM.NET and Lucene

Tags: .net, lucene, lucene.net, ikvm

I am using Lucene.Net but there are some interesting Java components for Lucene (especially analyzers) that haven't been ported to Lucene.NET yet so maybe IKVM is a better choice. Some research has shown that IKVM seems to work pretty well, but I haven't seen anything regarding Lucene.

Does anybody have experience running Lucene with IKVM.NET and can share his impressions?

Thanks

Comment: Do not quite have an answer for you, since I am in the same boat. In fact it might be worthwhile to try it out and open-source it.

Answer (score 2):

We are using Lucene through IKVM in a big C#-project. It works very well, also the performance is quite good. We also using the highlighter component - as described under the link in the post above.

But also you should keep an eye on Lucene.Net in the future. It is now a official apache top-level-project (http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/08/Lucene-net). So i guess it will catch up to Lucene (Java) in some time..